# Tomcat 7 (Virtual hosts?)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, virtual-hosts

I want use my web application on port 8082 (for example), and it is working correctly. But I want to leave connection on port 8080 (with default Tomcat page), can I do it and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need edit the conf/server.xml to add another Service, such as

```
<Service name="for_host1"> 
    <Connector port="8082" .. />
     <Engine name="Catalina_host1" defaultHost="stimpy">
        <Host name="stimpy" appBase="stimpyapps"/>
    </Engine> 
</Service> 
<Service name="default"> 
    <Connector port="8080" .. />
     <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="ren">
        <Host name="ren"    appBase="renapps"/>
    </Engine> 
</Service>
```

Comment: If you don't mind allowing both ports to serve the same set of applications, then you don't even need an extra `<Service>`: just add another `<Connector>`.

Answer (score 1):

you could install and run 2 or more tomcat servers simultaneous and have each tomcat listen to different ports