# Set up Virtual Hosts in Tomcat 7 for HP Fortify

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, virtualhost, fortify

I have an internal web app hosted by Tomcat 7 running on Windows Server 2008 R2. Users access the site from this URL: http://servername:8080/ssc. I'd rather users access the site from here instead: http://fortify

By default, Tomcat uses port 8080:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

My initial thought was to update that to use port 80 or would it be better to add a connector?

Or would it be better still to have a second service as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001282/tomcat-7-virtual-hosts)?

Comment: The referred link is about running two or more Tomcat instances or running on different port whereas you want to run your Tomcat application without port.

I strongly recommend to use mod_jk connector to achieve you this goal.

Comment: this http://serverfault.com/questions/256195/apache-2-2-17-tomcat-7-on-windows-server could help you. this link is also helpful http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/dedicated/tomcat_with_apache_on_windows_x64

Comment: Doesn't mod_jk require the Apache web server? I'm not opposed to installing it, but for my implementation I only have Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to guidance from Ghayel I now have this working! Here's how to do it:

1. Install Apache
2. Install the mod_jk connector into the Apache modules folder
3. Create a workers.properties file with these lines and drop it into the Tomcat conf folder:

   `worker.list=fortify
   worker.fortify.port=8009
   worker.fortify.host=fortifytest
   worker.fortify.type=ajp13`
4. Modify the Apache httpd.conf by adding these lines to the very end of the file:

   `LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
   JkWorkersFile "c:/apache/tomcat/conf/workers.properties"
   JkLogFile "c:/apache/tomcat/conf/from_apache_mod_jk.log"
   JkLogLevel info
   JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"`


   `<VirtualHost fortifytest:80>
     ServerName fortifytest
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule ^/$ /ssc [PT,L]
     JkMount /* fortify
     ErrorLog "logs/fortifytest-error.log"
     CustomLog "logs/fortifytest-access.log" common
   </VirtualHost>`
5. Restart Tomcat then restart Apache

Now I can use http://fortifytest instead of http://servername:8080/ssc.

EDIT: The PT (pass-through) flag is very crucial here. Without that flag the re-write rule did not function properly for my scenario.